# touch button with hold and unhold events to send different data in android

Tags: events, button, touch

i want a button that will send a data to a Bluetooth device when the button get touched once. and after removing the touch the button should send another data once. it's like when i touch the button and hold it, it'll only send a string like 'A' and when the touch removed it'll send another string like 'C'. i am a beginner. here is my code with two button but now i want only one button to control.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String TAG = "bluetooth1";

  Button btnOn, btnOff;

  private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
  private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
  private OutputStream outStream = null;

  private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


  private static String address = "98:D3:31:30:27:BD";


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);
    btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    checkBTState();
 // i want one button here for touch event 
    btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        sendData("A");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });

    btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        sendData("C");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
  }

  private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
          try {
              final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
              return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
          }
      }
      return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e1.getMessage() + ".");
    } 
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
    try {
      btSocket.connect();
      Log.d(TAG, "...Connection ok...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      try {
        btSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

    try {
      outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

    if (outStream != null) {
      try {
        outStream.flush();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    try     {
      btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
  }

  private void checkBTState() {
    if(btAdapter==null) { 
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
    } else {
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
      } else {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  private void errorExit(String title, String message){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
  }

  private void sendData(String message) {
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

    Log.d(TAG, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

    try {
      outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
      if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00")) 
        msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
        msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

        errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);       
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve the following by this and it's works perfect

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
      sendData("A");
      return true;
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      sendData("C");
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```